# JavaScript query params returning white space instead "+"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a set of code that will get query params and will pass it to another function.
But when I get the req.query (HELLO+WORLD) but when I get that and pass it to another function it gives me.
(HELLO WORLD). I want the exact + sign instead of white space.

//samplecode

```
 var Token = req.query["cust-Token"];
     const CustomerParams = { CustomerToken: Token };
    console.log(CustomerParams)
```

sample cust-Token = 'UHSXHD4323+HDS+11123' - this is the token I am getting and need to pass to another function but after fetching it is like:

//after fetching

cust-Token = 'UHSXHD4323 HDS 11123'

- sign replaced with white space.

Comment: You could turn it into a string then you `str.replaceAll(' ', '+')`

Comment: Lots of servers will automatically decode the encoded query params.  Why must the `+` be there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on your server

```js
const cust_Token = 'UHSXHD4323+HDS+11123'
console.log(encodeURIComponent(cust_Token))  // on server
console.log(decodeURIComponent(cust_Token))  // on client
```